# Where can I find articles on folder structures for websites?

Tags: web, n-tier-architecture, directory-structure

I'm creating an n-tier website with a number of projects. I'd like to follow best practice rules in terms of structure.

Are there any articles relating to folder structures available or does anyone have a good pattern that they use themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a PHP site, I normally have a .htaccess file that redirects all requests to a single file that then handles routing. For this MVC setup I'd do something like this:

```
/web_root
  /public
    /css
    /js
    /images
    index.php
  /app
    /lib
    /models
    /routes
    /templates
    bootstrap.php
```

I would then force my apache to server the `/web_root/public/` directory as the document root allowing users only to have access to my 'public' files...all of my logic would be hidden within `/web_root/app` for added security.